# avoid raw generic type in inheritance/delegation structure

Tags: java, generics, structure, delegation

My problem is quite complex and hard to explain, so I built a smaller example. It's still complex, but let me try my best...
You can download the full example here: https://mega.co.nz/#!400lSbqa!NoyflWYk6uaQToVDEwXyn22Bdcn_6GdTxB6dPUfU5FU

I recommend importing this into your favourite IDE and playing around.

---

Imagine you are programming a multiplayer game. It is supposed to have a world with entities. The code should be split into server, client, and shared stuff.

Each of my entities consist of 3 files:

- the base, which contains shared code and resources like the name
- the clientside, which derive the base and contain rendering etc.
- the serverside, which also derive the base and contain network events etc.

Because I can only derive from one class but want my client/server entities to have some shared code too, I tried it with a delegation-style structure. Let's name the actual entity [default], mark interfaces with *'s and `extends / implements` with `<-`

```
- *BaseEntity*
- [DefaultBaseEntity] <- *BaseEntity*

- *ClientEntity* <- *BaseEntity*
- [DefaultClientEntity] <- [DefaultBaseEntity], *ClientEntity*

- *ServerEntity* <- *BaseEntity*
- [DefaultServerEntity] <- [DefaultBaseEntity], *ServerEntity*
```

This way, I can also duck-typing-access The server/client specific implementations plus the base implementations with only holding ClientEntity/ServerEntity.

Now I want to program a world containing those entities. The world's code shall also be split into three parts and be generic to either contain server or client entities.

```
package base;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class BaseWorld<E extends BaseEntity> {

    private List<E> entities;

    public BaseWorld() {
        entities = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addEntity(E entity) {
        entity.setWorld(this);
        entities.add(entity);
    }

    public List<E> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void doStuffWithBuilding(E entity) {
        entity.doBasestuff();
    }

}
```

---

```
package client;

import base.BaseWorld;

public class ClientWorld extends BaseWorld<ClientEntity>{

}
```

---

```
package server;

import base.BaseWorld;

public class ServerWorld extends BaseWorld<ServerEntity> {

}
```

---

As you see, I am giving my entities a backreference to the world they are in. **And this contains the actual problem.**

Here's a look into the corresponding entity code:

```
package base;

public class DefaultBaseEntity implements BaseEntity {

    private BaseWorld world;

    @Override
    public void doBasestuff() {
        System.out.println("I am base entity");
    }

    @Override
    public void setWorld(BaseWorld world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseWorld getWorld() {
        return world;
    }

}
```

Now this works, **but** BaseWorld is a raw type. Obviously, every IDE starts to complain. I also do not want to suppress warnings.

I cannot use wildcard types like `BaseWorld<? extends BaseEntity>` either, because they produce compile errors, when I call world methods like doStuffWithBuilding():

```
package client;

import base.DefaultBaseEntity;

public class DefaultClientEntity extends DefaultBaseEntity implements ClientEntity {

    @Override
    public void doClientstuff() {
        System.out.println("I am client");
        getWorld().doStuffWithBuilding(this);
    }

}
```

> The method doStuffWithBuilding(capture#1-of ? extends BaseEntity) in
>   the type BaseWorld is not
>   applicable for the arguments (DefaultClientEntity)

Is there any solution to this? I tried removing the set/getWorld() from the base interface and adding it to client and server, but that was very clunky and causes a lot of repitition because of the delegation.

Comment: I'd say you're overcomplicating your rather simple problem with all the inheritance stuff and generics. For one, I don't understand why would you want your world to extend Entity. Is world an Entity? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: @MightyPork `BaseWorld` does not extend `Entity`, it just has a type parameter that extends `BaseEntity`.

Comment: @MightyPork World does not extend entity. As I said, I minimized the problem here. In reality, this structure seems to give me the most flexibility for the bigger project it's embedded into

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I haven't done java in far too long. Still it looks more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get around this by parameterizing DefaultBaseEntity:

```
public class DefaultBaseEntity <E extends BaseEntity>
        implements BaseEntity<E> {

    private BaseWorld<E> world;

    // ...
}

public class DefaultClientEntity extends DefaultBaseEntity<ClientEntity>
        implements ClientEntity {
    // ...
}
```

Observe that `DefaultClientEntity` does not need to be parameterized (at least not for this purpose), even though its superclass is.

**Update**:
Furthermore, you can perform analogous parameterization with your interfaces:

```
interface BaseEntity <E extends BaseEntity> {
    public void setWorld(BaseWorld<E> world);
    // ...
}

interface ClientEntity extends BaseEntity<ClientEntity> {
    // ...
}
```

The example `DefaultBaseEntity` code above is updated to implement that generic `BaseEntity` interface.

Comment: Just parameterizing `DefaultBaseEntity` is not enough. The type parameters have to be carried forward through everything.

Comment: This seems like the solution. Although it brings a new problem. I defined `setWorld(BaseWorld<? extends BaseEntity> world);` in the BaseEntity interface. Now if I try to overwrite that in DefaultBaseEntity, it won't let me parameterize it with E, because it is recognized as a different function then. EDIT: This is the problem @Jesper described

Comment: @Felk, you cannot use a wildcard there.  Instead parameterize `BaseEntity` the same way you do `DefaultBaseEntity`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Jesper, type parameters do *not* inherently need to be carried through to subclasses.  The code I presented compiles.  Whether it adequately solves the OP's issue is a different question, but it sure would be preferable to avoid parameterizing dozens of classes if it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put the right type parameters everywhere:

```
public interface BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity> {
    public void doBasestuff();
    public void setWorld(BaseWorld<E> world);
    public BaseWorld<E> getWorld();
}

public interface ClientEntity<E extends BaseEntity> extends BaseEntity<E> { ... }

public class DefaultBaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity> implements BaseEntity<E> {

    private BaseWorld<E> world;

    @Override
    public void doBasestuff() {
        System.out.println("I am base entity");
    }

    @Override
    public void setWorld(BaseWorld<E> world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseWorld<E> getWorld() {
        return world;
    }

}

public class DefaultClientEntity extends DefaultBaseEntity<DefaultClientEntity>
    implements ClientEntity<DefaultClientEntity> { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was almost the solution. Had to replace the `BaseEntity`s with `BaseEntity<E>`'s to fix new raw types. Now it looks acceptable and has no errors or suppressions

Comment: I tried implementing this into my codebase. It works, but since I had to parameterize the interface, it looks really messy. Is there a way of avoiding this?